# Is it possible to do this simple query without a having clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    pid, SUM(hourslogged) AS totalhours 
FROM
    flightskills
GROUP BY
    pid
HAVING
    SUM(hourslogged) > 1000
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: You can always use a subquery and a `where`.  Your query is syntactically incorrect.  The `having` goes after the `group by`.

Comment: It is not good to change the core of your query once you already asked it and you have answers! It makes the whole discussion irrelevant and pointless.

Comment: There are various hacks you could use to avoid the `HAVING` keyword specifically, but what's wrong with it? Is there some underlying issue, or are you just trying to pick off random keywords?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are focused on the `having` clause when you can get rid of the `join`:

```
select f.pid, sum (f.hourslogged) as Totalhours 
from flightskills f
group by f.pid
having sum(f.hourslogged) > 1000;
```

If you are really deadset against the `having` use a subquery:

```
select f.*
from (select f.pid, sum (f.hourslogged) as Totalhours 
      from flightskills f
      group by f.pid
     ) f
where Totalhours > 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH f as (select pid, sum (hourslogged) as Totalhours 
from flightskills
group by pid)
SELECT p.pid, f.Totalhours
from pilots p join f on p.pid = f.pid
where f.Totalhours > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a window function:

```
SELECT f.pid, f.totalhours
FROM (SELECT pid, SUM(hours) AS totalhours FROM flightskills GROUP BY pid) f
WHERE f.totalhours > 1000
```